# removing first row from dataframe destroys dataframe structure

Tags: r, dataframe

I have following dataframe:

```
>part_individual
                  AATGG     
unit              "AATGG"   
human_female      "980993"  
human_male        "1150320" 
bonobo_female     "2674508" 
bonobo_male       "3121386" 
chimpanzee_female "642629"  
chimpanzee_male   "514293"  
gorilla_female    "4459693" 
gorilla_male      "3430239" 
orangutan_female  "2839394" 
orangutan_male    "3251095" 
gibbon_female     "106825.4"
gibbon_male       "147886.3"
skewed_human      "1.17"    
skewed_bonobo     "1.17"    
skewed_chimpanzee "0.8"     
skewed_gorilla    "0.77"    
skewed_orangutan  "1.14"    
skewed_gibbon     "1.38"
```

As you can see, first row is redundant. However, I cannot figure out how to remove it while keeping the structure of the dataframe. After removing first row with this command:

part_individual=part_individual[-1,]

the structure gets destroyed:

```
     human_female        human_male     bonobo_female       bonobo_male chimpanzee_female   chimpanzee_male 
         "980993"         "1150320"         "2674508"         "3121386"          "642629"          "514293" 
   gorilla_female      gorilla_male  orangutan_female    orangutan_male     gibbon_female       gibbon_male 
        "4459693"         "3430239"         "2839394"         "3251095"        "106825.4"        "147886.3" 
     skewed_human     skewed_bonobo skewed_chimpanzee    skewed_gorilla  skewed_orangutan     skewed_gibbon 
           "1.17"            "1.17"             "0.8"            "0.77"            "1.14"            "1.38"
```

How could I avoid this behavior please?

Comment: You need to do `part_individual[-1, , drop = FALSE]`

Comment: Thank you, that was it!!

Comment: (For the documentation of this behavior and the `drop=` option, see `help("[.data.frame")`).

Comment: @RichardScriven would it be best to move that to an answer so this question can be marked as answered?  Or is this perhaps a dup?